# Haar measure : trace of an operator squared and square of the trace of an operator

Tags: density-matrix, haar-distribution, linear-algebra

From doing numerical simulations, I seem to have the following results :
$$ \int d \rho \,\, \text{Tr}(\rho M^\dagger M) = \frac{1}{d} \text{Tr}(M^\dagger M) $$
and
$$ \int d \rho \,\, \left|\text{Tr}(\rho M)\right|^2 = \frac{1}{d(d+1)} \left(\text{Tr}(M^\dagger M) + |\text{Tr}(M)|^2 \right) $$

Where $\int d\rho$ is the normalized integral over the density matrices of pure states (Haar distribution) and $M$ a complex matrix.

However I am quite stumped as to how would one prove that ? Do any of you have any insights ?

Cheers and thanks.

Comment: Weingarten calculus. https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.14890 In essence, it uses that representations of $U^{\otimes N}$ can be decomposed in terms of irreps of the permutation group -- Schur-Weyl duality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first integral can be written as
$$\int dU \, \operatorname{tr}(U \rho U^\dagger M^\dagger M)
= \operatorname{tr}\left[\left(
\int dU\, U\rho U^\dagger \right)M^\dagger M\right],$$
where the integration is performed over the uniform Haar measure in the space of unitaries. You then get the result using the identity
$$
\int dU\, UX U^\dagger = \frac{\operatorname{tr}(X) I}{d}$$
for any linear operator $X$, for the special case of $\rho$ pure. This has been discussed and proved multiple times on the site already, see *e.g.* *[Density matrices of multiples copies of a single Haar-Random state](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/29337/55)* and links therein.

For the other identity, write the LHS as
$$\int dU \operatorname{tr}(U\rho U^\dagger  M)^2
= \sum\int dU\, U_{ij} U_{k\ell} \bar U_{mn} \bar U_{pq} \rho_{jn} \rho_{\ell q} M_{mi}  M_{pk}$$
where I wrote expliciting the matrix components. Using the formulae to integrate polynomials of the unitary matrices, which you can find *e.g.* in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weingarten_function), you have
$$
\int_{U_d} dU U_{ij} U_{k\ell} \bar U_{mn}
\bar U_{pq}= \frac{1}{d^2-1}\left[ (\delta_{im}\delta_{jn} \delta_{kp}\delta_{\ell q} + \delta_{ip}\delta_{jq} \delta_{km}\delta_{\ell n} )  - \frac1d
(\delta_{im} \delta_{jq} \delta_{kp}\delta_{\ell n}
+\delta_{ip} \delta_{jn} \delta_{km}\delta_{\ell q})
\right]$$
which contracting the indices should give back your expression.

Comment: I really appreciate your solution. Thank you !

I did see the second equation pop out on the website often, and felt like it must appear in the solution, but as I was not very familiar with the Haar measure, I didn't exactly know how to link $\int d\rho$ and $\int dU$, to which your first equation gives an answer to. So thank you again !